# Cómo hago para generar un código de inserción para una parte de mi código? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy tratando de clonar esta página https://www.lifeofdiscipline.com/my-habits la cual es un Habit-tracker. Entre tantas cosas, esta permite embeber el hábito que vos quieras (genera un link especial para ese hábito, algo asi: https://www.lifeofdiscipline.com/notion/habit/cldavuycm000nl50f) para luego pegarlo en Notion. Al ingresar a ese link generado se puede ver solo ese hábito.
Mi pregunta es **como genero ese nuevo link** y **como hago para que este vinculado solamente con el hábito seleccionado**. De este modo, un usuario podría copiar el link del hábito y pegarlo en Notion por ejemplo.

La verdad es que estoy bastante bloqueado. Lo único que hice fue generar el id del hábito pero nada más que eso.

```
function generateEmbedLink(habit) {
  // Generate a unique ID for the habit
  const habitId = generateUniqueId(habit);
  // Construct the embed link
  const embedLink = `https://www.mi-habit-tracker-website.com/embed/${habitId}`;
  // Copy the link to the user's clipboard
  copyToClipboard(embedLink);
}

function generateUniqueId(habit) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene que ver con ¿cómo generar un ID en javascript? o con ¿cómo generar un ID de hábito en `lifeofdiscipline.com`? Son cosas totalmente distintas. Te sugiero que leas [ask] y [example]

Comment: @AndresGardiol mi pregunta tiene que ver más con cómo generar un ID en js. lifeofdiscipline.com es el ejemplo que estoy siguiendo para hacer mi página. Gracias por las recomendaciones.

Comment: Respecto a la generación de ID en JS te comparto esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-do-i-create-a-guid-uuid en donde explican lo que quieres hacer y por qué NO usar `Math.random()`. Por otro lado, tu pregunta en realidad son 2 preguntas. La de generar el ID y la de "como hago para que este vinculado solamente con el hábito seleccionado". Esta última es una pregunta mucho más compleja y súper amplia, ya que hay muchas formas de hacerlo y las respuestas que te puedan dar seguramente estén basadas en opiniones. Te recomiendo que te limites a una sola pregunta específica.

Comment: Y cuando hayas intentado algo sobre vincular solamente un hábito (Recuerda que debes demostrar que has intentado algo) puedes crear una nueva pregunta si es que tienes un error específico.